# Missing Operating System!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, uefi

ı have macbookPro Mid2012 with yosmeite osx and win7 with bottcamp. yesterday with live ubuntu usb ı startedn my mac and click install ubuntu 14.04.3. lts icon on ubuntu after that ı canceled installing. after a few time ı need go macintosh but ı cann't boot from mac or bootcamp win7. there is an error says "missing operating system" how can ı fix it. probably damaged mbr efi system. now ı only use live ubuntu usb. pls help me on ubuntu os to fix this problem.

Comment: At some point durring install it says that changes are irreversible, or something like that. Boot back into the live cd and show us the output of `sudo fdisk -l`